# Flask-login's Class User(UserMixin) using Flask-MongoEngine

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-login, flask-mongoengine

Unable to overcome the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

This is part of the Flask-Login, where I need to create to create a user class as described [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class).

Initially was using PyMongo, but realised that I can't implement a class using a model of the document in the collection. Therefore I am now using Flask-MongoEngine.

Current code is as follows:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

class User(UserMixin, db.Document):
   meta = {'collection': 'users_in_db'}
   email = db.StringField()
   password = db.StringField()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
   return User.objects(email=email).first()
```

If I add `print User.objects(email=email).first()` in `@login_manager.user_loader` I get the correct user entry printed. So I think I am making a mistake around how I set up the class.